# How to setup MSBuild tool in Jenkins with Windows slave and Linux master

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Master Environment:

- Jenkins 2.45
- Ubuntu 16.04

Slave Environment:

- Jenkins 2.32.2
- Windows 2008 R2
- VS 2013

I have a master/slave setup with a linux master and a windows slave. I have a few .NET projects I would like to setup to build on the windows slave.
The relevant part of my Pipeline descriptor looks like this:

```
stage('Build') {

    bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" My_Solution.sln /m /target:clean,build /p:Configuration=Debug;VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
}
```

In a non-slave Jenkins server in Windows with the MSBuild plugin installed you can find an entry in

> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System

for setting up the MSBuild tool. This options does not exist on the Linux master with the MSBuild plugin installed. Nor is there an option in

> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> ${Node Name} -> Configure

The only tools that can be added from the Slave node configuration are:

- Git
- Maven
- SonarQube

How can I configure the MSBuild tool for my Windows slave?

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being with the version of the MSBuild plugin on the Master node. After upgrading the MSBuild plugin to 1.26 and installing the latest pipeline plugins the MSBuild section was available for configuration in

> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration

on the master node.